# Switching images after a mouse hover in a Flash banner

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently making a flash banner for a customer, which is acting all glitchy.

**The brief**

I'm making an actionscript, which toggles between 3 images, with an interval of 5000ms. The function should however not initiate till 2 seconds of hover is present. I've created 2 frames. Frame 1 for idle, and when hovering for 2 seconds it goes to frame 2.

**The problem**

The whole thing is acting all up, and the 2 second delay i've added using `setTimeout` just works once, and continues from earlier, say i hovered for 1 second and move the cursor away, it only needs 1 second the next time. If i keep my mouse over it, it kinda stacks the fade effects so that the images randomly fade with under 800ms in interval. This is very odd?

**The goal**

I want the banner to be idle, till i hover my mouse over it for 2 seconds. If i remove my mouse, the whole thing should reset again.

Whilst active, it should fade between 3 images, interval 5000ms.

Thanks in advance! :)

**The code**

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.clearInterval;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;

stop();

image_1.alpha=1;
image_2.alpha=1;
image_3.alpha=1;

var current = 1;
var interval1;
var url1 = "http://www.danbolig.dk/bolig/koebenhavn/2200/udlejningsejendom/956tl000227-956";
var url2 = "http://www.danbolig.dk/bolig/gladsaxe/2880/andet/956tl000245-956";
var url3 = "http://www.danbolig.dk/butik/ErhvervKobenhavn";

setTimeout(intervall, 2000);

function intervall():void
{
    interval1 = setInterval(imageFades, 5000);
}

function imageFades():void
{
    if(current == 1)
    {
        current = 2;
        image_2.alpha=1;
        new Tween(image_1, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    }
    else if(current == 2)
    {
        current = 3;
        new Tween(image_2, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    }
    else if(current == 3)
    {
        current = 1;
        new Tween(image_1, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
    }
}

linkOverlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, detoggleAnimation);

function detoggleAnimation(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
    clearInterval(interval1);
    image_1.alpha = 1;
    image_2.alpha = 1;
    image_3.alpha = 1;
}

linkOverlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoLink);

function gotoLink(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(current == 1)
    {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url1));
    }
    else if(current == 2)
    {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url2));
    }
    else if(current == 3)
    {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url3));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, just to clarify:   **Frame 1:**  an idle screen, does nothing but wait for a mouse over event that lasts for 2 seconds (which moves the timeline to frame 2) - the mouse over is cummulative meaning hovering for 1 second two times counts?.    **Frame 2:**  Rotates 3 images (one every 5 seconds), until mouse out, which returns to frame 1 and resets the 2 seconds of mouse over?

Comment: @LDMS : Exactly my point. I'm not too great at expressing myself correctly. But yes, that clarification matches just great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues.  First, you don't go to frame 2 ever that I can see.  Second, you're not listening for a hover event anywhere, but just launching right into it after 2 seconds regardless of mouse - this is what makes it only work once.

Using `Timer`s is a much better approach, hopefully my code comments can explain everything.

This assumes no frame 2, just have everything on frame 1 along with this code:  (untested)

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.clearInterval;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.utils.Timer;

stop();

//lets keep all the image stuffs in an array, this way you can add as many as you want without change any code but the array.
var images:Array = [
    { img: image_1, url: "http://www.danbolig.dk/bolig/koebenhavn/2200/udlejningsejendom/956tl000227-956" },
    { img: image_2, url: "http://www.danbolig.dk/bolig/gladsaxe/2880/andet/956tl000245-956" },
    { img: image_3, url: "http://www.danbolig.dk/butik/ErhvervKobenhavn" }
];

var current = images.length-1; //cur index of the images array (first element is 0)

//a timer to keep track of the mouse hover
var hoverTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1); //tick every 2 seconds, only 1 time
hoverTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goActive);  //when the timer ticks, run the goActive function

//a timer to rotate the images
var transitionTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000); //tick every 5 seconds, until told to stop
transitionTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, imageFades)

linkOverlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);

//hide these initially
image_1.alpha=0;
image_2.alpha=0;
image_3.alpha=0;

function mouseOver(e:Event):void {
    if(!hoverTimer.running) hoverTimer.start(); //start the hover timer now that the mouse is over
}

//the mouse has been over for 2 seconds now, start rotating the images
function goActive(e:Event = null):void {
    imageFades(); //fade in the first image right away
    transitionTimer.start(); //start the transition timer so it changes every 5 seconds
}

function fadeOutCurrent() {
    //fade out the current image (if not already alpha=0)
    if(images[current].img.alpha > 0){
        new Tween(images[current].img, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, images[current].img.alpha, 0, 1, true);
    }
}

function imageFades(e:Event = null):void
{
    hoverTimer.reset();

    fadeOutCurrent();

    current++; //add one to the current index
    if (current >= images.length) current = 0; //go back to index 0 if the current index is greater than the amount in the array

    //fade in the NEW current item
    new Tween(images[current].img, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, images[current].img.alpha, 1, 1, true);
}

//events for resetting when leaving content area 
linkOverlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, detoggleAnimation);  //when the mouse leave the linkOverlay element (if it takes up the whole swf, use the next line instead)
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, detoggleAnimation); //when the mouse leaves the swf
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, detoggleAnimation);    //when the focus leaves the swf

function detoggleAnimation(event:Event):void {
    transitionTimer.reset(); //reset/stop the image fading
    fadeOutCurrent();
}

linkOverlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoLink);

function gotoLink(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(images[current].url));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your responsive 
I unfortunately encounter this error on trial:

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Banner_1_fla::MainTimeline/imageFades(). Expected 0, got 1.
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Comment: Sorry,  forgot to put in the required event parameter on the imageFades methid.   I updated the answer

Comment: I've finally had a chance to test the code and everything works.  Let me know if you have any additional issues.